# Error while installing VirtualBox-guest-additions?

Tags: 12.04, server, virtualbox

Windows 7 as host machine and Ubuntu 12.04 server as guest (Virtual Box)

Got this error while installing VirtualBox-guest-additions

```
The gcc utility was not found.If the following module compilation fails then this could
be the reason & you should try installing it. Building the main guest additions module..fail !!
(Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find what went wrong)
could not find the X.org or XFree86 Window System, skipping !!
```

I read the /var/log/vboxadd-install.log file & found this which is again i can't understood

```
/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.20/src/vboxguest-4.3.20/build_in_tmp: 62: /opt/VBox$t/VBox
GuestAdditions-4.3.20/src/vboxguest-4.3.20/build_in_tmp: make: not found

Creating user for the guest additions.`Creating udev rule for the guest additions kernel module.`
```

What's this all means ?  Please help me out guys .Thanks

Comment: @RPi_Awesomeness Thanks for edit but seems like that was not the code !! Let it be , please help me out now

Comment: In order to be able to compile and install the guest additions you need to install the appropriate compiler (**gcc**) and the **make** utility (`sudo apt-get install gcc make`). See https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm

Answer (score 2):

Unless you really need features only available with 4.3.20, I would suggest to use the guest additions from the Ubuntu [repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/virtualbox-guest-dkms):

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils
```

Restart your VM to apply the changes.

Comment: This applies only if the GA version matches the VBox version installed in the host, which is very unlikely with a Windows host.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install gcc.

```
 sudo apt-get install gcc
```

will get you started.